# vue 'public' files not included after webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have a set of files in the `public` folder of my vue-js app and I'm expecting them to be copied over into the `wwwroot` folder when the project is built, per this information in the docs:

> Any static assets placed in the public folder will simply be copied and not go through webpack. You need to reference them using absolute paths. ([ref](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder))

The files are `favicon.ico` and other favicon pngs of various sizes, as well as a `site.webmanifest`. I'm not referencing these in any code, other than using the example provided (to the best of my knowledge) referencing them in the `index.html`:

```html
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="<%= BASE_URL %>apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="<%= BASE_URL %>site.webmanifest">
```

How do I get these to be copied to the base of my generated site when I build? All the directly referenced assets are included (css, fonts, etc.), but none of the static files in `public` except index.html itself.

For reference, in case it's applicable, here's my vue.config.js:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "./wwwroot"),
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        config
            .plugin('html')
            .tap((args) => {
                args[0].template = './ClientApp/public/index.html'
                return args
            })

        config.entry("app")
            .clear()
            .add("./ClientApp/src/main.js")
            .end()

        config.resolve.alias
            .set("@", path.join(__dirname, "./ClientApp"))
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking something - thanks for any assistance.